# ClassCastException after applying PathProperties

Tags: java, playframework, classcastexception, ebean, playframework-2.4

I'm trying to apply some `PathProperties` to my `Finders` but I keep getting this error :

> [ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.avaje.ebean.bean.BeanCollection]

It only happens when I have a `List<...>` called in my `PathProperties` like so :

```
PathProperties pathProperties = PathProperties.parse("(*,historique(*))");
List<Devi> test = Devi.find.apply(pathProperties).findList();
```

Where my `Finder` is defined like this :

```
public static Finder<String,Devi> find = new Finder<String,Devi>(Devi.class);
```

Here, the object `Devi` is full of public variables, that I am able to call without any issue (the PathProperties `"(*)"` works), but when I try to access a List of objects inside this object (here, `public List<Histo> historique`), it won't work. I tried, and I'm also able to access an object within the object, as long as it's not a List.

I'm kinda lost here, I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: Could you append Devi.java to your question?

Comment: The file is way too big for me to append it here. What are you looking for in it exactly?

Comment: share more info about `Devi.find.apply(pathProperties).findList();`

Comment: What do you mean? The `PathProperties` and the `Finder` are described above.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/issues/591 , this  is a bug triggered by initializing the ArrayList.  Without the initialization it will apparently work.

Comment: Well, I'm not initializing any ArrayList here :/